# MKAnnotationView not working when library imported by customer app

Tags: swift, cocoapods, mkannotation, mkannotationview, apple-maps

We have a SDK that we ship via Cocoapods. It contains a map that makes some api calls and then renders custom annotations on the map. I’m running into an issue with MKAnnotationView when trying to integrate with a customer app.

At dev time and in our sample apps, the annotations appear correctly. When the customer tries to integrate it, the map annotations don’t work.

Has anyone ever seen this issue before? I'm not getting any error messages.

The relevant `MKMapViewDelegate` code is

```swift
public func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        if let place = annotation as? Place {
            os_log("Returning saved annotation", log: OSLog.map, type: .info)
            return mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: PlacesAnnotationView.ReuseID) ??
                PlacesAnnotationView(annotation: place, reuseIdentifier: PlacesAnnotationView.ReuseID)
        }
        
        os_log("Place was nil", log: OSLog.map, type: .error)
        
        return nil
    }
    
    public func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        if let tileOverlay = overlay as? MKTileOverlay {
            return MKTileOverlayRenderer(tileOverlay: tileOverlay)
        }
        return MKOverlayRenderer(overlay: overlay)
    }
```

The ReuseID is in the format of `OurName_PlacesAnnotation`.

In `viewDidLoad`, I'm calling `map.register(PlacesAnnotationView.self, forAnnotationViewWithReuseIdentifier: "placesViewReuseIdentitier")`.

[[image]]
[[image]]

Comment: You are asking whether somebody else has the same issue that you have when they are using the same SDK?  That's all you want to know?  Does it have a name or a URL?  It comes with a map?  If it does, why do you still use `MKMapView`?  Just out of curiocity...

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make that clear. What I'm asking is whether anyone else has ever run into an issue where annotations just don't work in some applications but work otherwise. The SDK does come with a map and does use MKMapView. Has that been deprecated? It's a private SDK so not really shareable.